# Looking for some help setting up Magento

Tags: magento2, server

I have been hosting several Magento websites via shared hosting for the last 24-months now.  Setting them up is a doddle using cPanel etc.   My web host simpleservers have let me down causing the production site to go down for 4 weeks!  I then switched to shared hosting with 1&1 but similar problems with memory filling up just with a template and two products installed.  I contacted Dell Business and they are delivering two top spec R420 rack servers for me to host the website myself.  One server will run the database and the other the magento website. I've also upgraded to a Fibre Optic Broadband line with a static IP but need to help getting it all going.  I've never set up servers before.  Please can anyone recommend a suitable OS (I've been toying with the idea of Ubuntu Server as its got a GUI).     Please can someone help...I have a limited budget but need to get up and running again!

BTW the site will have about 3 sub-designs and around 1000 unique SKUs.

Comment: Why don't you just get a VPS server instead? You wasting just as much if not more money doing everything else than just going with a simpler solution. A semi managed VPS will hold your magneto website fine.

Comment: Got the site installed...its empty currently but since the install and clicking on the 'backend'  or 'frontend' on final confirmation screen, the site goes very slow and not loading the styles.  It seems to be an error of the base URL.  the fixed IP of the web server is 92.19.218.30 - I've got my domain to point here as a DNS.  Any ideas to get this upto full speed? Could it be the firewall or permissions?

Comment: When using the Local IP 192.168.1.7 I can connect directly to the server and magento website no problems - how can I convert the Magento site to WAN from LAN?

Comment: Managed to get this working... but only works on WAN from outside the LAN. Set up Port Forwarding in the TalkTalk Super Router. Now live. [http://stika.co](http://stika.co) - Next step will be to configure my own SSL and get a secure payment protocol - PayPal is fine for now but would be nice to drop their fees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, I suppose it's fair to look at what you *do* have, a couple nice servers showing up capable of running serious solutions.

I think jumping right in and deciding to host yourself is going to give you headaches. Since you have the servers, maybe it would be worth your time to talk to some providers about co-location services. You get a box in their cage with a nice uplink as well as someone in the building to fix things if your server needs a disk swap.

Do this for a year or so and then, if you think you're ready, call the boxes back home and host it all yourself. At that point you might have learned a thing or two and can better provide your own infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks for all your advice so far. The hardware arrives today so hope to make a start over the weekend.  I looked a VPS by the costs soon mount up after two years.

Answer (score 2):

But to answer your question I would suggest Ubuntu. Definitely my favorite to use works with almost any program window servers are limited in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend Ubuntu or CentOS - but if the situation you described above is daunting already (meaning if you don't feel comfortable managing the servers) - Server configuration / Frontend Cacheing / Etc - Roshni's answer of switching to a VPS is probably the best solution.  You definitely should not be having problems with memory in a store with two items.  It may be propitious to post some logs and see why you are getting such load on your store, maybe other resources are being used.

Comment: Joshua Chavanne is right, from my experience major hosting providers do not allow magneto websites to be installed in shared web hosting, such as 1 and 1 and GoDaddy(sucks :l) since it takes up alot of memory. This is probably why you are having so many problems.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having your own infrastruture, try AWS cloud based hosting of your site, it will free you from many activities also you can create backup if one your server is down also you can add resources as and when needed just on button clicks.

Comment: So first question: should I install the two serve with MAAS?  I've read the info at http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/orientation.html#do-i-need-maas and it seems like the best way forward.  Is best for a pure Magento Webserver?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS now installed... Just getting a command prompt, how do I turn this into a Magento website???

Comment: use pre-configred magento image by bitnami here is the link "https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B007OUYR4Y"

Comment: i just get a 404 error with this link. I need to guidance on setting up LAMP stack split over two machines, i have Ubuntu running on both computers now. How do i configure one as the database server and the other as a web server?  or would you recommend a complete xeon server per web site? Also, how can I do daily backups without slowing the server down with too many scripts?

Answer (score 0):

http://ubuntuserverguide.com/2014/06/how-to-install-lamp-in-ubuntu-server-14-04-lts.html

This explains how to set-up a LAMP Stack, how does it work for my two server set-up one running the website and other running the database?

Alex